# How should one lift a heavy object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, biology

The lower lumbar region of the spine is susceptible to abuse while resisting excessive bending caused by the moment about the hip of a force F from lifting a weight:

[image]

Here is a (mirrored) diagram of the lift above:
[image]

I am trying to find the safest angles to lift such a weight. In the case of a barbell such as in the first image we are clearly limited by the bar having to go in front of our knees. In other cases such as a heavy small box or kettlebell this may not be a restriction and we can get a more upright back by letting our knees go forward.

My analysis goes as follows:
$$\vec{back}=b[cos\alpha,sin\alpha,0]$$
$$\vec{arm}=-a[sin\beta,cos\beta,0]$$
$$\vec{r}=\vec{back}+\vec{arm}=[bcos\alpha-asin\beta,bsin\alpha-acos\beta,0]$$
$$\vec{F}=[0,-F,0]$$
Torque from F around hip:
$$\vec{\tau}=\vec{r} \times \vec{F} \text{ where } \vec{r} = \vec{back} + \vec{arm}$$
$$|\tau|=F(b \cos\alpha- a \sin\beta)$$
So it seems that in order to save our lower backs we should try to lift as upright as possible (large $\alpha$) and with shoulders as far as possible in front of weight (large $\beta$).
It also seems that lifting with the weight in front of the shoulders is a really bad idea.

**Is my static analysis correct?**

Typical values for a deadlift as seen in the first image may be:
$\alpha=15^\circ$ and $\beta=5^\circ$
In which case having the shoulders in front of the weight results in a $\sin(5^\circ)/\cos(15^\circ) = 8 \%$ reduction in torque around the hip (assuming length of back ~ length of arms which typically is roughly correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I agree with the analysis and it is a nice concise explanation. However, this does not capture why dead-lifts which are intended to exercise higher $b$ while being safe, also follow the strategy outlined. Maybe that is a good future problem.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that my two criteria oppose each others. Upright back leads to a squat and shoulders forward leads to a deadlift: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/43443/how-does-one-lift-a-heavy-box-up-from-the-ground. I may try to minimize torque at the hips as a function of alpha, beta and knee and ankle angle later to see if that favours the squat or the deadlift.